# Use TensorBoard with Keras Tuner

Tags: tensorboard, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I ran into an apparent circular dependency trying to use log data for TensorBoard during a hyper-parameter search done with [Keras Tuner](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-tuner), for a model built with TF2. The typical setup for the latter needs to set up the Tensorboard callback in the tuner's `search()` method, which wraps the model's `fit()` method.

```
from kerastuner.tuners import RandomSearch
tuner = RandomSearch(build_model, #this method builds the model
             hyperparameters=hp, objective='val_accuracy')
tuner.search(x=train_x, y=train_y,
             validation_data=(val_x, val_y),
             callbacks=[tensorboard_cb]
```

In practice, the `tensorboard_cb` callback method needs to set up the directory where data will be logged *and this directory has to be unique to each trial*. A common way is to do this by naming the directory based on the current timestamp, with code like below.

```
log_dir = time.strftime('trial_%Y_%m_%d-%H_%M_%S')
tensorboard_cb = TensorBoard(log_dir)
```

This works when training a model with known hyper-parameters. However, when doing hyper-parameters search, I have to define and specify the TensorBoard callback before invoking `tuner.search()`. This is the problem: `tuner.search()` will invoke `build_model()` multiple times and each of these trials should have its own TensorBoard directory. Ideally defining `log_dir` will be done inside `build_model()` but the Keras Tuner search API forces the TensorBoard to be defined outside of that function.

**TL;DR:** TensorBoard gets data through a callback and requires one log directory per *trial*, but Keras Tuner requires defining the callback once for the entire *search*, before performing it,  not per trial. How can unique directories per trial be defined in this case?

Answer (score 2):

The keras tuner creates a subdir for each run (statement is probably version dependent).

I guess finding the *right version mix* is of importance.

Here is how it works for me, in *jupyterlab*.

prerequisite:

1. pip requirements

```
    keras-tuner==1.0.1
    tensorboard==2.1.1
    tensorflow==2.1.0
    Keras==2.2.4
    jupyterlab==1.1.4
```

(2.) jupyterlab installed, built and running [standard compile arguments: production:minimize]

Here is the actual code. First i define the log folder and the callback

```
# run parameter
log_dir = "logs/" + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%m%d-%H%M")

# training meta
stop_callback = EarlyStopping(
    monitor='loss', patience=1, verbose=0, mode='auto')

hist_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(
    log_dir=log_dir,
    histogram_freq=1,
    embeddings_freq=1,
    write_graph=True,
    update_freq='batch')

print("log_dir", log_dir)
```

Then i define my hypermodel, which i do not want to disclose. Afterwards
i set up the hyper parameter search

```py
from kerastuner.tuners import Hyperband

hypermodel = get_my_hpyermodel()

tuner = Hyperband(
    hypermodel
    max_epochs=40,
    objective='loss',
    executions_per_trial=5,
    directory=log_dir,
    project_name='test'
)
```

which i then execute

```py
tuner.search(
    train_data,
    labels,
    epochs=10,
    validation_data=(val_data, val_labels),
    callbacks=[hist_callback],
    use_multiprocessing=True)

tuner.search_space_summary()
```

While the notebook with this code searches for adequate hyper parameters i control the loss in **another notebook**. Since tf V2 tensorboard can be called via a [magic function](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/tensorboard_in_notebooks)

Cell 1

```
import tensorboard
```

Cell 2

```
%load_ext tensorboard
```

Cell 3

```
%tensorboard --logdir 'logs/'
```

Sitenote: Since i run jupyterlab in a docker container i have to specifiy the appropriate address and port for tensorboard and also forward this in the dockerfile.

*The result* is not really predictable for me... I did not understand yet, when i can expect histograms and distributions in tensorboard.
Some runs the loading time seems really excessive... so have **patience**

Under scalars i find a list of the turns as follows

"logdir"/"model_has"/execution[iter]/[train/validation]

E.g.
0101-1010/bb7981e03d05b05106d8a35923353ec46570e4b6/execution0/train
0101-1010/bb7981e03d05b05106d8a35923353ec46570e4b6/execution0/validation